# Setting every nth range in php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying achieve a specific style for every 3rd 4th and 5th element in loop. I know it is possible in css but I want to learn it in php too. The following code inserts class to every 3rd element.

```
global $post_num;
if ( ++$post_num % 3 == 0 )
    $class = 'whatever';
echo $class;
```

I've tried `if ( ++$post_num % 3 == 0 ) && ( ++$post_num % 4 == 0 ) && ( ++$post_num % 5 == 0 )`,  but it doesn't work

Comment: I think you would want a loop somewhere.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest

Comment: oh yeah, kind of obvious now. ` if ( ++$post_num % 3 == 0 ) && ( ++$post_num % 4 == 0 ) && ( ++$post_num % 5 == 0 )` will add 1 to $post_num 3 times. break that out into a separate line.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be you are attempting to increment the `$post_num` multiple times within the `if` clause. Try this instead.

```
global $post_num;
$class = '';
if (($post_num % 3 == 0) || ($post_num % 4 == 0) || ($post_num % 5 == 0)) {
  $class = 'whatever';
  ++$post_num;
}
echo $class;
```

But that said, I am still unclear on what role the `++$post_num` plays since wouldn’t this logic be placed in a larger loop?  So wouldn’t this work?

```
global $post_num;
$class = '';
if (($post_num % 3 == 0) || ($post_num % 4 == 0) || ($post_num % 5 == 0)) {
  $class = 'whatever';
}
echo $class;
```

Meaning `$post_num` is a value based on the content rolling through your script logic? And this clause will simply take the value of `$post_num` and act on it? If you have more code to illustrate the structure you have in place that would help.

**EDIT** Just adding my own loop for this example so it’s clearer what is happening.

```
for ($post_num = 1; $post_num <= 20; $post_num++) {
  $class = '';
  if (($post_num % 3 == 0) || ($post_num % 4 == 0) || ($post_num % 5 == 0)) {
    $class = 'whatever';
  }
  echo $post_num . ' | ' . $class . '<br />';
}
```

But looking at the output it might not be what you expect, since 3rd, 4th or 5th with a modulus (`%`) operator will encompass a whole range of divisible items:

```
1 | 
2 | 
3 | whatever
4 | whatever
5 | whatever
6 | whatever
7 | 
8 | whatever
9 | whatever
10 | whatever
11 | 
12 | whatever
13 | 
14 | 
15 | whatever
16 | whatever
17 | 
18 | whatever
19 | 
20 | whatever
```

**ANOTHER EDIT** Okay, I think I got it now. I am assigning the value of the modulus to the largest number to `$post_count`, then I set an array for the items you want to assign a class to in `$class_value_array` and then the `if` clause now uses `in_array()` to validate.

```
for ($post_num = 1; $post_num <= 20; $post_num++) {
  $class = '';
  $post_count = $post_num % 5;
  $class_value_array = array(0, 3, 4);
  if (in_array($post_count, $class_value_array)) {
    $class = 'whatever';
  }
  echo $post_count . ' | ' . $post_num . ' | ' . $class . '<br />';
}
```

The output is now:

```
1 | 1 | 
2 | 2 | 
3 | 3 | whatever
4 | 4 | whatever
0 | 5 | whatever
1 | 6 | 
2 | 7 | 
3 | 8 | whatever
4 | 9 | whatever
0 | 10 | whatever
1 | 11 | 
2 | 12 | 
3 | 13 | whatever
4 | 14 | whatever
0 | 15 | whatever
1 | 16 | 
2 | 17 | 
3 | 18 | whatever
4 | 19 | whatever
0 | 20 | whatever
```

Which I am pretty sure is what you are looking for.

Comment: The first code adds class to first post only, whereas the second code applies class to all the posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ++$post_num % 3 == 0 ) && ( ++$post_num % 4 == 0 ) && ( ++$post_num % 5 == 0 )
```

will give you the class on every gcd(3,4,5) = 60th row. Just do:

```
if  ( ++$post_num % 5 == 0 )
```

for five

```
if( ++$post_num % 4 == 0 )
```

for 4, etc.

Comment: I tested it before posting question. Unfortunately its not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to apply a separate style to the third, fourth, and fifth item. Why complicate things? Just add a class indicating that the element is the third, fourth, or fifth element in the series. You can use CSS to determine if an element is a combination. You don't want to use CSS which I assume means you don't want to use the `nth-child` selector.

This code is not CSS/HTML only, you can easily change the code from applying a class to executing a function, for example.

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < 300; $i++ ) {
  $classes = array();
  if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) $classes[] = 'tri';
  if ( $i % 4 == 0 ) $classes[] = 'quad';
  if ( $i % 5 == 0 ) $classes[] = 'quint'; 

  echo "<div class='" . implode(' ', $classes), "'>Number " . $i . "</div>";
}
```

Just style the classes at this point. Here's the output:

```
<div class="tri quad quint">Number 0</div>
<div class="">Number 1</div>
<div class="">Number 2</div>
<div class="tri">Number 3</div>
<div class="quad">Number 4</div>
<div class="quint">Number 5</div>
<div class="tri">Number 6</div>
<div class="">Number 7</div>
<div class="quad">Number 8</div>
<div class="tri">Number 9</div>
<div class="quint">Number 10</div>
```